# how to convert a string into json in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a string that i get from git when i do this

```
> git show xxxx | head -3

commit 34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas
Author: John Doe <john@doe.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800
```

I need to convert this string that prints out to console into a json format using python so the format would be (i am writing this in a script)

```
{'commit': '34343asdfasd343adfas', 'Author': 'john doe', 'date': 'wed jun 25'}
```

Currently I am trying to manually split by the first space in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on your example:

```
>>> txt='''\
... commit 34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas
... Author: John Doe <john@doe.com>
... Date:   Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800'''
>>> json.dumps({k:v for k,v in re.findall(r'^([^\s]+)\s+(.+?)$', txt, re.M)})
{"commit": "34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas", "Date:": "Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800", "Author:": "John Doe <john@doe.com>"}
```

If you have the `git...` part, just split it off:

```
>>> json.dumps({k:v for k,v in re.findall(r'^([^\s]+)\s+(.+?)$', 
                           txt.partition('\n\n')[2], re.M)})
```

And if you want to loose the `:` just change the regex capturing group to say so:

```
>>> json.dumps({k:v for k,v in re.findall(r'^(\w+):?\s+(.+?)$', 
                          txt.partition('\n\n')[2], re.M)})
{"Date": "Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800", "commit": "34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas", "Author": "John Doe <john@doe.com>"}
```

And if you want to loose the email address:

```
>>> json.dumps({k:v for k,v in re.findall(r'^(\w+):?\s+(.+?)(?:\s*<[^>]*>)?$', 
                     txt.partition('\n\n')[2], re.M)})
{"Date": "Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800", 
 "commit": "34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas", "Author": "John Doe"}
```

Comment: nice way slicker than mine

Comment: @dawg OP asked for a bit customized values, not all following end of lines after simple split.

Answer (score 0):

## Trying to follow exact format of values

OP asks for a bit customized values, which are not exact values left after removing labeling word. For that purpose we have to tackle line by line separately.

Take the text input and split it to lines:

```
>>> text = """commit 34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas
... Author: John Doe <john@doe.com>
... Date:   Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800"""
...
>>> lines = text.split("\n")
>>> lines
['commit 34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas',
 'Author: John Doe <john@doe.com>',
 'Date:   Wed Jun 25 09:51:49 2014 +0800']
```

Assume fixed order of lines and process part by part:

```
>>> dct = {}
>>> dct["commit"] = lines[0].split()[1]
>>> dct["Author"] = lines[1].split(": ")[1].split(" <")[0]
>>> dct["Date"] = " ".join(lines[2].split(": ")[1].split()[:3])
```

creating final dictionary:

```
>>> dct
{'Author': 'John Doe',
 'Date': 'Wed Jun 25',
 'commit': '34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas'}
```

which can be dumped to a string:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(dct)
'{"Date": "Wed Jun 25", "commit": "34343asdfasdf343434asdfasdfas", "Author": "John Doe"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
results = subproccess.Popen("git show xxxx | head -3",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()[0].strip()
data = {}
for line in results.splitlines():
     key,value = line.split(" ",1)
     data[re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]","",key)] = value
json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Um yeah, not really sure why this is here!